# How can I accessing the scala play plugin from Build.scala

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I am not a very sophisticated SBT user, although I have been using it casually for several years. I have made multiple project builds before, but (as always) this particular 'split one project into sub projects' has hit a snag.

**The problem**

I have a Build.sbt file in the root directory of a project that had the following line in it

```
lazy val commonPlay = Project(id = "commonPlay", base=file("modules/commonPlay")).
dependsOn(core).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

The important line in it is 'enablePlugins(PlayScala)'. As well as this build.sbt file, I have a plugins.sbt file in the project directory that declared a number of plugins, including "com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.1"

I am now migrating the project to use a Build.scala file, and in the Build.scala (which is in the project subdirectory) I have the following code

```
  def playModule(dir: String) =  
           Project(id = dir, base = file(dir),  settings = defaultSettings).
                   enablePlugins(PlayScala)    

   lazy val core = module("core")
```

This gives me a 'not found' exception at the PlayScala.

**To Date**

I've tried messing around with plugins.sbt: adding it under project/project, but decided that I didn't know what I was doing, and I have something of a phobia about not understanding this sort of detail. I had a good read of http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Getting-Started/Using-Plugins.html which was very helpful to my understanding, but didn't actually answer the problem.

My expectation is that all I have to do is specify an import, but I'm not sure how to work out what that import would be

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried `import play.PlayScala`?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [this test](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/sbt-test/play-sbt-plugin/secret/project/Build.scala) of the Play framework itself, you need to use `play.PlayScala`.

```
Project(id = dir, base = file(dir)).enablePlugins(play.PlayScala)
```